# Help Identify Bluetooth Headset Plug

Tags: audio, identification, plug

Can anyone tell me what plug this is? Looks like a type of USB, but it's smaller than micro USB. It's being used on a Bluetooth motorcycle helmet kit, to connect stereo speakers and a microphone to the main unit.

I'm looking to order more of them so I can build a custom adapter to allow plugging in any headphones via 3.5mm jack.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a [UC-E6](https://www.google.com/search?q=uc-e6) USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Micro USB.   Here's the Wikipedia Page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Mini_and_Micro_connectors

Comment: Can you be more specific? I see micro a, micro b, and micro ab but the pin count and shape doesn't match any of those. Also I have micro usb b type on my phone (htc desire HD) and this plug is slightly smaller than that.